# Time series data pre-processing for anomaly detection

Tags: svm, data-processing, anomaly-detection

I am using a good volume of time series data that spans over two months [November and December 2015] containing time-stamp observations. A total of about 6 million samples. I use the portion of clean data in my dataset to train a One class SVM.

To note here is that I have scaled and normalised the data accordingly but I am using the processed raw time-stamps to train it. After I trained the OCSVM - testing it on my test data does not work good. The results are very inaccurate.

> The reason I think is because I am training it with time-stamp. But I am
>   not sure.
>
> *Would it be more advised to pre-process and get the mean of
>   each hour and then training it, rather than each observation as it is*?

I have been trying to find how to process time series data before training it but I was unable to find any. Any suggestions or reference to papers will be appreciated

*Note: I have asked the same question on CV as well.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to normalize all data, this makes a huge difference. *LibSVM* uses the following formular which normalizes the data column-wise. Normalize your training data and implement the normalization also for prediction using the normalizing-values gained from training.

[image]

Another thing to mention here is, training a `One-Class-SVM` is very hard. So, maybe you should use the standard binary classification approach and use a second class which catches all miss-classifications for your target class. You'll be also able to make use of some `Hard-Negative-Mining`.